# Socket module in python is hellish annoying to learn

Tags: python, sockets

Alright this is the code:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(),4334))

while True:
full_msg = ''
new_msg = True
headersize =10
while True:
    msg = s.recv(10)
    if new_msg:
        print("new msg len:", msg[:headersize])
        msglen = int(msg[:headersize])
        new_msg = True

    print(f"full message length: {msglen}")

    full_msg += msg.decode("utf-8")

    print(len(full_msg))

    if len(full_msg) - headersize == msglen:
        print("full msg recvd")
        print(full_msg[headersize:])
        new_msg = True
```

clientside code. Gives an error as follows down below

```
File "C:/Users/subha/Desktop/Pycharm projects/Snapshot virus/clienttest.py", line 13, in <module>
msglen = int(msg[:headersize])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'You have c'
```

can anybody help me with this. And btw tbh sockets code in python is really short and weird like its really frustrating to learn idk. I just feel its not understandable. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast the bytestring `b'You have c'` into an int. This does not work.

You are missing a `len()` function call there, because that is what I think you want to do:

So instead of using `msglen = int(msg[:headersize])` you should use:

`msglen = len(msg[:headersize])`

And yes, socket programming can be quite frustrating. But it's also kind of satisfying to establish such low-level communication. You just mixed up `len` and `int` here, that is not a big of a deal.

Comment: Thanks a lot! and sorry too this was an easy one to solve now I feel. Do you think transferring data like this in c++ would be algorithmically more understandable? because I just started learning c++ few days ago... Thanks a lot again :) the thing is I wasn't in the mood for solving errors today cus I felt so drained out :P